# "Select unused channels" does not work for one particular wav sample in FL Studio 11.1.0

Tags: fl-studio

I have a simple project (with some VST plugins and some .wav samples).

`Tools > Macros > Select unused channels` does not select **one particular unused** channel; however, it selects all other unused channels.
I have now triple-checked this *problematic* channel manually, and I'm 100% sure, that this channel is NOT used anywhere. It is even not bound to any mixer channel. So, the "select unused channels" option does NOT select one particular unused channel.

Has anyone ever had such a scenario? I have tried restarting the DAW, restart the PC, etc., nothing helps. Note, that other unused channels are being selected with this option.

Side-note: I use FL Studio since it was Fruity Loops (around 20 years for now).. and I'm not a beginner in this.. yet, I have never encountered such a problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that there is only one unused channel, and FL Studio will not select it? Or are there multiple unused channels, and FL Studio just happens never to select a particular one of them? Or something else?

Comment: There is only one unused. Does it matter, however? it should select any X number of unused channels when I used this macros. Now I have just deliberately experimented cloning that channel (which is not identified as "unused") and the cloned version is selected when checking for "Select unused channel" macros.. but that particular channel does NOT want to work in this regard.. super strange.

Comment: Could be a bug, report to the dev team, alongside with the project night be useful to them!